# calculating with very big numbers in c

Tags: c, math, modulo

Im new to programming.
I want to calculate the modulo of a number which is in range from `[0,10^24]`.
For example: `(12 * 10^22) % 89`
I know that I can't do this with the usual data types like long, integer and so on.
How can I do this? Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206756/discussion-on-question-by-jbond-calculating-with-very-big-numbers-in-c).

Comment: jbond, For `a mod b`, and  "a number which is in range from [0,10^24]",does that apply to `a` and `b`?  If not, what is the range for each `a, b`?  Knowing range limitations is important in C.

Answer (score 5):

The expression shown can be easily calculated by reducing modulo 89 after each operation:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    //  Initialize a product.
    int t = 1;

    //  Calculate 10^22 (modulo 89) by multiplying by 10 (modulo 89) 22 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; ++i)
        t = t * 10 % 89;

    //  Multiply by 12 (modulo 89).
    t = t * 12 % 89;

    //  Show the result.
    printf("%d\n", t);
}
```

Comment: Minor optimization: `i < 11` and `t * 100`

Comment: Better:  You can easily implement an O(log(n)) solution, for exponent n, rather then the O(n) solution posted here.  Standard integer exponentiation, with the addition of the mod.

Comment: @TomKarzes: The key concept for this class exercise or contest problem is simply to reduce modulo 89. For students who are just learning that, introducing more sophisticated algorithms would complicate the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

The largest guaranteed C data type is a uint64_t (see stdint.h), which holds up to 2^64 - 1. I think it is preferable to maintain conformance to standard C when possible, so I'd suggest a way of simplifying the problem first so as to not use data types wider than that. For that, let's borrow from a modular arithmetic proof:

`xy % z == ((x % z) * (y % z)) % z`

From this, we can gather that, `(12 * 10^22) % 89 == (12 % 89 * 10^11 % 89 * 10^11 %89) % 89` This new version certainly isn't as pretty, but it does make all the factors fit nicely into standard C data types. Simplification prior to computation such as this can be used for all the data in your range.

However, there is the problem of having storing the value you want to modulo in the first place. Clarification on what the use case is might make for a more applicable answer. For instance, is the value being stored in a string, perhaps from user input?

Alternatively, you can make use of certain libraries designed for dealing with really big numbers. I don't know which would be best for your purposes (I don't even know what OS you're on), but if you'd like to explore those options, a simple web search for "bignum", "arbitrary-precision", or "infinite-precision" libraries should give you what you want.

Comment: `(12 * 10^22) % 89 == (12 % 89 * 10^11 % 89 * 10^11 %89) % 89` works because `10^22` is not a prime.  Yet OP is looking for range of  `[0,10^24]` which includes many large primes.  "Simplification prior to computation" is a good idea, but a prime prevents general application of this approach.

Comment: I misread. I confused you and Eric Postpischil. I apologize; I'm still trying to learn this interface. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers say, you can get by with regular integers in this case.

If you really need very large integers (like in many cryptographic applications), there are several open source libraries around. Check out the [GNU MP library](https://gmplib.org) or [Flint (Fast Library for Number Theory](http://flintlib.org), take a peek at the (header only!) C++ [precision package](https://github.com/possibly-wrong/precision) or take a peek at [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software). Most of them are available as packages for your favorite Linux distrtibution.

Many languages handle large integers transparently, GNU's bc (at your nearest Linux box) uses them.